# Sorting even and odd numbers inside an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to split the array into `odd` and `even` numbers. Note that sorting numbers in the final result does not matter. I'm compiling the code and the output contains some bug. My code arranges `odd` numbers correctly while the `even` numbers are giving me some trouble. Could somebody please help me out with the arrangement of `even` numbers?

Basically, I arrange `odd` numbers in the left side of the array and have `oddPos = 0` in the beginning; `even` numbers are in the right side and the positioning starts from the very end of the array `evenPos = myArray.length - 1`.

```
public class EvenOddArray {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};


        int oddPos = 0;
        int evenPos = myArray.length - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i] % 2 == 0){
                myArray[evenPos] = myArray[i];
                evenPos--;
            }
            else{
                myArray[oddPos] = myArray[i];
                oddPos++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 5 7 2 4 6 6 4 2
```

Comment: You're overwriting inputs you haven't processed yet. Either use a new array for the output, or swap the target position with an unprocessed position.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, could you please explain overwriting inputs that are not processed yet ? I don't understand that part

Comment: Unless you really need to avoid the overhead of an additional array allocation, I'd recommend use separate arrays for input and output. It's both simpler to implement and easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are editing the same `myArray` array while reading from it. So what happens is,

You insert 6 into the `myArray[7]` th position, in the 6th iteration of the loop. So, during the 7th iteration when you read the `myArray[7]`, it is 6. Not 8. Because, you have over written 8 with 6 in the previous iteration.

Therefore, use a separate array to hold the results. Hope you get the point.

You can do something like this,

```
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] resultArray = new int[myArray.length];
    int oddPos = 0;
    int evenPos = myArray.length - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i] % 2 == 0){
            resultArray[evenPos] = myArray[i];
            evenPos--;
        }
        else{
            resultArray[oddPos] = myArray[i];
            oddPos++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is a correct answer. and it's so clear. but its not the fastest one and it uses more memory. than the one I suggested and updated by @CodesInChaos

Comment: @hasan83 Yes, you are correct. But My intention was to address the issue by making least amount of changes and without adding more logic to swap the elements. But I think when it comes to speed there is no big issue with this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot..! Returned the favor! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
int current = 0;
int evenPos = myArray.Length - 1;
while (current < evenPos) {
    if (myArray[current] % 2 == 0) {
        swap(myArray, evenPos, current);
        evenPos--;
    } else {
        current++;
    }
}
```

A squeezed funny version:

```
for (int curPos=0, evenPos=myArray.length-1; curPos < evenPos;)
    if (myArray[curPos] % 2 == 0)
        swap(myArray, evenPos--, curPos);
    else
        curPos++;
```

More fun version:

```
for (int curPos=0, evenPos=myArray.length-1; curPos < evenPos;)
    swap(myArray, curPos, myArray[curPos]%2==0 ? evenPos-- : curPos++);
```

**explanation:**

> You don't have to swap values when the number is odd. you only
>   increase the current counter.
>
> you can't use the for loop counter as an index to the array too. to
>   not miss the numbers that gets swapped to the counter index not
>   processed. this is the mistake that other answers didn't cover.

Comment: I'd change the end condition to compare `current` and `evenPos`. Once you're beyond `evenPos`, all you're doing is swapping the element with itself. `i` is rather pointless as well, so I'd replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop. Something like `while(current < evenPos)`

Comment: I like it. faster and less code. edit it to get recognition :)

Comment: Nice solution! Although I made an optimized version of your solution, avoiding to swap even numbers that are already on the right side of the array. :)

Comment: In case that the number is even the number is swapped with itself

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what happens with each Iteration of your for loop.

- Original:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
- 1st Iter:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
- 2nd Iter:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  2
- 3rd Iter:  1 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  2
- 4th Iter:  1 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 4  2
- 5th Iter:  1 3 5 4 5 6 7 8 4  2
- 6th Iter:  1 3 5 4 5 6 7 6 4  2
- 7th Iter:  1 3 5 7 5 6 7 6 4  2
- 8th Iter:  1 3 5 7 5 6 6 6 4  2
- 9th Iter:  1 3 5 7 5 4 6 6 4  2
- 10th Iter: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 6 4  2

As you can see, you are modifying the array "inplace". You are modifying the array without using all the values. For example, look at 9, It gets over written before it is ever accessed. So, your algo is wrong.

Suggestions:

- Use a new array to hold the results as in tibzon's answer
- Use swapping instead of overwriting. You have to update your algo accordingly. I was going to provide one. But Murenik already provided one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my optimized version, which uses around half of the swaps compared to the @hasan83 version.

```
    int n = myArray.length;
    int oddPos = 0;
    int evenPos = n - 1;
    while (true) {
        while (oddPos < n && myArray[oddPos] % 2 == 1) {
            oddPos++;
        }
        while (evenPos >= 0 && myArray[evenPos] % 2 == 0) {
            evenPos--;
        }
        if (oddPos >= evenPos) break;
        swap(myArray, oddPos, evenPos);
    }
```